# Setting truncation and wrap in Emacs config file

Tags: emacs

I'm using Emacs 23 in a Debian GNU/Linux variant distribution. In a default Emacs session  launched with `emacs -q` (to confirm the settings) I execute the following to setup the environment I would like:

```
 M-x toggle-truncate-lines <RET>
 M-x set-variable word-wrap t <RET>
```

I leave `visual-line-mode` set to whatever it's default is.

I would like to place these settings into my ~/.emacs file so that they are always active. I did this with the following:

```
(setq word-wrap t)
(setq-default truncate-lines nil)
(setq visual-line-mode nil)
```

However, these settings do not replicate the environment I would like. Long lines are not wrapped -- they extend beyond the right edge. If I then run `M-x toggle-truncate-lines` they wrap as I want, but not on word boundaries, so the word-wrap setting has also not taken effect. I also tried setting `truncate-lines` in ~/.emacs to `t`, but this made no difference. The documentation for `truncate-lines` reads as follows, so setting this variable to `nil` appears to be what I am looking for:

```
*Non-nil means do not display continuation lines.
Instead, give each line of text just one screen line.
```

I have not split any windows horizontally, so `truncate-partial-width-windows` does not apply.

How do I setup the environment I would like in ~/.emacs?

Answer (score 2):

if toggle-truncate-lines is given a negative argument, it allways switches truncating off.

So:

```
(setq-default word-wrap t)
(toggle-truncate-lines -1)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to replicate the behavior of the function call `toggle-truncate-lines`, why not just do:

```
(toggle-truncate-lines)
```

in your `~/.emacs` file?

Of course, you can also put `(setq word-wrap t)` in there too, though I suspect you should do `(setq-default word-wrap t)`, since variable `word-wrap` becomes buffer-local when set in any way.

Comment: I have `(toggle-truncate-lines)` and `(setq-default word-wrap t)` in my `~/.emacs` file. The word-wrap  appears to be working. However, long lines extend beyond the right edge regardless of whether I have `(toggle-truncate-lines)` in my `~/.emacs` or not. Truncating long lines is buffer-local I think? Maybe that's why including it in `~/.emacs` is not having an effect. That's why I also tried (see question) to set `(truncate-lines)`, which also didn't work.